# AWS API Gateway and Lambda integration with resources on different Cloudformation stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, swagger-2.0

I want to integrate a lambda function to an API gateway so that when I do a POST to the path defined on the API gateway the Lambda gets executed and returns a value.

Now, in my current project we currently have 2 Cloudformation templates:
- One that is generic and contains the definition of recourses common to all development environments
- And another non-generic one that deploys different resources depending on the environment passed as a paramater (dev, prod, etc).

In the non generic I have defined the lambda function, as well as the Deployment and Stage.
In the generic CF template I have defined the APIGateway as this:

```
Resources:
  RecargakiApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Body:
        swagger: "2.0"
        info:
          version: "VersionTimestamp"
          title: "Some API"
        host: "some.host"
        schemes:
          - "https"
        paths:
          /payment:
            post:
              produces:
                - "application/json"
              responses:
                "200":
                  description: "200 response"
                  schema:
                    $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                credentials: 
                  Fn::ImportValue:
                    "lambda-credentials-outputvalue-in-another-generic-stack"
                uri: !Sub
                  - "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda::${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${lambdaName}/invocations"
                  - lambdaName: "${stageVariables.lambda_name}"
                responses:
                  default:
                    statusCode: "200"
                passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
                timeoutInMillis: 5000
                httpMethod: "POST"
                contentHandling: "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
                type: "aws_proxy"
        definitions:
          Empty:
            type: "object"
            title: "Empty Schema"
      Description: "Desc"
      Name: "Name"
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - REGIONAL
```

Now according to the [docs on AWS proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/aws-api-gateway-stage-variables-reference.html) it is possible to construct the lambda uri like this:

```
arn:aws:apigateway:<region>:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda::<account_id>:function:${stageVariables.<function_variable_name>}/invocations
```

I tried to construct the uri according to that format but I get this error:

```
Unable to put integration on 'POST' for resource at path '/payment': Invalid function ARN or invalid uri (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException
```

In all the examples I've seen, people assume the Lambda function to be integrated is located in the same CF template/stack as the API Gateway resource, but I have no idea how to reference the function's ARN and/or name in the Swagger definition of the API Gateway when the function is actually located in a different CF stack.

I've also tried referencing a stage variable that would contain the full URI like:

```
uri: "${stageVariables.functionURI}" # the URI would be constructed in the non generic stack in the format stated by the docs
```

But it fails with:

```
Unable to put integration on 'POST' for resource at path '/payment': Invalid ARN specified in the request (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is it, but the `uri` where you're constructing the whole ARN, there's a extra colon when constructing the Lambda ARN - `arn:aws:lambda::` vs. `arn:aws:lambda:`. See the Lambda ARN syntax https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-lambda

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe it was just that, it must have slipped right past me.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Happy to help. I know very well how tricky these things can get ;)